# <hr> between 2 rows in GridView

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview

I have a nice working grid view but I want to have a `<hr>` tag between every row.
My GridView has 2 columns, so it will be rendered as:

```
<table>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y>/td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y>/td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to have:

```
<table>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `AlternatingRowStyle` intelligently to acheive this. IMHO there no straightforward way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, you are expecting a line for each TR.

Why dont you **try with CSS**

```
tr { border-bottom:2px solid #eee;}
```

or

```
tr td { border-bottom:2px solid #eee;} /* border for all tds and not tr */
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView does a lot, but when you want finer-grained control over the layout, a [Repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.7.2) can offer more.

The linked page includes an example showing how you can create the entire HTML table within the Repeater, starting with the header template, continuing in item templates, and ending in the footer template. It doesn't take much to set up and can be very powerful.